# Why does browser treat localhost and 127.0.0.1 differently?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In a simple oauth call the application is called from localhost and the return url comes in 127.0.0.1 but browser gives and error as 
Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".
Why does browser treat them differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One is a name, the other is an ip address.

Its just a security feature, to stop cross domain requests etc.

127.0.0.1 != localhost,  localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 it is not the same "domain".